# Doctrine 1.2: Memcache network timeout(0)

Tags: php, linux, doctrine, memcached, symfony-1.4

I have been working with Memcache and PHP for a long time and was everything great but now I have been getting this error after every response. The will trigger by Doctrine 1.2.

Notice: MemcachePool::getextendedstats(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Network timeout (0) in /var/www/yoveo/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Cache/Memcache.php on line 141

And it's current memcache version with memcahed on linux ubuntu machine with PHP 5.4.17 version. I can not understand what to do now with this Network timeout issue. What can be done to solve this.

Currently,I have only one local machine with linux ubuntu.

Unsure if it's a memcache daemon or client issue.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure memcached is running:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached status
```

If not, start it with:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached start
```